# Confused by when to use -ent and -ence (e.g innocent, innocence, eloquent, eloquence, patient, patience ...etc)

Tags: derivational-morphology

Is there a rule or guideline that can help to know the right tense to use at any given situation?

I'm currently learning by memorising phrases like *Be Patient*, *Have patience* but it is limiting.

Comment: Are you trying to understand when you want a noun and when an adjective?

Comment: Mainly it's a difference between adjective (-ent) and noun (-ence), though some of the adjective forms (eg, "innocent") are sometimes used as nouns.

Comment: @HotLicks yes! innocent and innocence typicallyI I was stuck at these two words and signed up for an account to post the question.

Comment: @Jalene - Understand that "innocent", when used as a noun, is basically short for "innocent person" -- it's the sort of "shorthand" that develops naturally when particular English word pairings are used frequently.

Comment: @tchrist From what I learned, adjective is use to describe noun. I have still yet to understand the sequence of sentence. Please share more if it helps me to understand how to use them correctly. Thank you.

Comment: @HotLicks For eg. "She is innocent" and I don't mean she is not guilty of crime but more of her characteristic. How do I differentiate that?

Comment: @Jalene - No different than saying "She is beautiful", implying a characteristic.  It's still an adjective.  "Innocent" has several different meanings.

Comment: Understand that in the basic sentence "X is Y", X is almost always a noun/pronoun, but Y can be a noun/pronoun or an adjective.